# Python script won't stop running

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly

I'm creating a dictionary for my map to aggregate all counties/states by latitude and longitude for a sales territory map however it won't stop running though I tried it just last night and it worked perfectly.

I've restarted several times.

```
Territory1 = ["Austin","Bay Area - SF","Bay Area - SV","Bold North","Chicago 1","Chicago 2","Dallas 1","Dallas 2","Desert","Georgia","Great Lakes","LA","LA 2","Maryland Metro","Metro Central","Metro East","Mid South","Mid-Atlantic","Missouri Valley","New England 1","New England 2","NY Metro","OC/LA","Ohio Valley","Peninsula","Philly East","Philly West","PNW 1","PNW 2","PNW 3","Rockies","So Cal","South","SoVA"]

for territory in Territory1:

    territory_data = dict(
                        lat = df.loc[df["Territory1"]==territory,"Lat"],
                        lon = df.loc[df["Territory1"]==territory,"Lon"],
                        name = territory,
                        marker = dict(size = 8, opacity = 0.5),
                        type = 'scattermapbox')
    Territory1.append(territory_data)
```

What I want is an aggregated list that will show up in the map that users can click to see each territory individually (the territories are as listed in Territory1 list).

Comment: You are adding to the list as you traverse it. How would it ever reach the end?

Answer (score 3):

It will not stop because:

```
Territory1.append(territory_data)
```

**appends new elements** in the `Territory1` list and then

```
for territory in Territory1:
```

**does not reach an end.**

Probably you need: `results_list.append(territory_data)`

Answer (score 0):

As @serafeim said, you're iterating over a list while you're adding to it.

```
   Territory1 = ["Austin","Bay Area - SF","Bay Area - SV","Bold North","Chicago 1","Chicago 2","Dallas 1","Dallas 2","Desert","Georgia","Great Lakes","LA","LA 2","Maryland Metro","Metro Central","Metro East","Mid South","Mid-Atlantic","Missouri Valley","New England 1","New England 2","NY Metro","OC/LA","Ohio Valley","Peninsula","Philly East","Philly West","PNW 1","PNW 2","PNW 3","Rockies","So Cal","South","SoVA"]
   for territory in Territory1:

        territory_data = dict(
                          lat = df.loc[df["Territory1"]==territory,"Lat"],
                          lon = df.loc[df["Territory1"]==territory,"Lon"],
                          name = territory,
                          marker = dict(size = 8, opacity = 0.5),
                          type = 'scattermapbox')
        Territory1.append(territory_data)
```

I believe what you want to do is:

```
territory_dicts = {}
for territory in Territory1:
    temp_dict = dict(lat: df.loc[df["Territory1"]==territory,"Lat"],
                     lon: df.loc[df["Territory1"]==territory,"Lon"],
                     name: territory,
                     marker: dict(size = 8, opacity = 0.5),
                     type: 'scattermapbox')
    territory_dicts[territory] = temp_dict
```